# record video from rtsp on TextureView

Tags: java, android, xcode, android-studio

Hi I have the following code that simply displays an RTSP on a TextureView to then make a screenShot of the stream and save it as an image,

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(Uri.parse("rtsp://........./")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnCapture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    recordVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });
        }
    });
    recordVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
    recordVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

how can I record a portion of this video and save it as mp4? I made the start and stop buttons for recording the video Can I save the video between the start and stop?